# Maven, Ant, Dependency Resolution, How to Invoke Target in Another Project

Tags: maven, ant

I would like to “extend”, in one maven  project, an ant target defined in another Maven Project.

The base project “Project 1” defines an ant build file, with target “BaseDB”  that invokes a set of SQL scripts that create a database schema. This project gets built by Maven to a Jar containing the ant build.xml  and the dependent SQL scripts.

I would like to define a “Project 2” with an ant build file with a target “ExtensionDB” with depends =”BaseDB,LocalUpdateDB”. That is, ExtensionDB incorporates the BaseDB definitions by reference.

Ive played around with the dependency extensions provided by xmlns:artifact="antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant" without ever being able to resolve anything in Project1/Build.xml (let alone the SQL scripts upon which it is dependent)

Any ideas

Comment: Better thinking of use sql-maven-plugin to run the SQL scripts directly in Maven instead of the chaotic playing with Ant script. What would you like to use Maven or Ant ?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to have a lifecycle hook that extract the original Project1/Build.xml from its jar and put it in a place where you can refer it from Project2 build.xml.

(I'm not sure that I fully understand what you're trying to do, but I'd expect the ant extension to resolve the tasks (Java code), not the build.xml file itself.)